# Swift encode WhatsApp URL

Tags: swift

I would like to open a WhatsApp URL in my App, which I create in Swift. The URL scheme for WhatsApp is

```
whatsapp://send?text=
```

and my code look like:

```
        let originalMessage = NSLocalizedString("Open following url ", comment: "") + " " + "http://<url>.<com>/?=test"
        let escapedMessage = originalMessage.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!

        // Check if url will be opened
        guard let whatsAppUrl = NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=" + escapedMessage) else {
            print("error")
            return

        }

        // Open whatsapp url
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(whatsAppUrl) {
          print("ok")
        }
```

My issue is, that I have in my String which will I open with WhatsApp a question mark character "?". I tried to escape the character like:

```
"whatsapp://send?text=\"" + escapedMessage + "\""
```

But if I open the URL in WhatsApp, I get an empty String. Can someone help me or have a hint for me?

Comment: `"whatsapp://send?text=\"" + escapedMessage + "\""` Never do that. It is always wrong to construct a URL string by hand like this. Use NSURLComponents and NSURLQuery; that's what they are for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send static URL like this:

The Objective-C call to open one of these URLs is as follows:

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
}
```

In Swift:

```
let  whatsappURL = NSURL(string:"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!")
if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(whatsappURL!)) {
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(whatsappURL!);
}
```

From the link:

[I integrate WhatsApp into my app](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013)

Answer (score 0):

I think URLComponent is the best way to solve it.

```
let whatsAppHookup = "whatsapp://send"
let address = "https://www.swift.org/?page=1"
var urlComponent = URLComponents(string: whatsAppHookup)
let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "text", value: address)
urlComponent?.queryItems = [queryItem]

let url = urlComponent?.url
print(url?.absoluteString ?? "")
```